# How to convert org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName to string,Decimal type in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a JSON  like below

```
{"name":"method1","parameter1":"P1name","parameter2": 1.0}
```

I am loading my JSON file

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.json("C:/Users/test/Desktop/te.txt") 
scala> df.show()
```

```
+-------+----------+----------+
|   name|parameter1|parameter2|
+-------+----------+----------+
|method1|    P1name|    1.0   |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

I have a function like below:

```
def method1(P1:String, P2:Double)={
     |  print(P1)
         print(P2)
     | }
```

I am calling my method1 based on column name after executing below code it should execute method1.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("methodCalling", when($"name" === "method1", method1($"parameter1",$"parameter2")).otherwise(when($"name" === "method2", method2($"parameter1",$"parameter2")))).show(false)
```

But I am getting bellow error.

```
<console>:63: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: String
```

Please let me know how to convert org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName data type to String

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your `method1` returns Unit. I don't think Spark SQL will like that.

Comment: Hi Mtoto,based on json parameter name value (method1) ,i want to cal required method here it is method1and I need to pass parameter1 and parameter 2 values  to method1

Comment: i am getting error because of type mismatch, so i want to convert org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName datatype to required datatype

Comment: Can you add your desirable output here? and you are passing direct column that's why you are getting this error, you have to send column value instead of the whole column.

Comment: My output should be  P1name, and 1.0. i.e method1 print statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
scala> def method1(P1:String, P2:Double): Int = {
     |   println(P1)
     |   println(P2)
     |   0
     | }

scala> def method2(P1:String, P2:Double): Int = {
     |   println(P1)
     |   println(P2)
     |   1
     | }

df.withColumn("methodCalling", when($"name" === "method1", method1(df.select($"parameter1").map(_.getString(0)).collect.head,df.select($"parameter2").map(_.getDouble(0)).collect.head))
  .otherwise(when($"name" === "method2", method2(df.select($"parameter1").map(_.getString(0)).collect.head,df.select($"parameter2").map(_.getDouble(0)).collect.head)))).show

//output

P1name
1.0
+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
|   name|parameter1|parameter2|methodCalling|
+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
|method1|    P1name|       1.0|            0|
+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

You have to return something from your method otherwise it will retun unit and it will give error after printing result:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.when(functions.scala:1245)
  ... 50 elided
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi ,thanks for reply .but I am getting error like value otherwise is not a member of Int

Comment: Sorry i have given wrong parameter.It is working as expected. Thanks :)

Comment: Okay, no worries :)

Comment: But both functions(method1,method2) are executing ,but i want to execute only method1 function.but i am getting output like print statement (P1name
1.0
P1name
1.0) ,please help me on this.

Comment: Please Help me on this how to resolve above problem  .it is calling method2 also

Comment: when and otherwise is adding a column with some condition and it always runs all the method which is called by its. If the value is present it inserts the value which is return by the method otherwise `null`.

Answer (score 5):

When you pass arguments as

```
method1($"parameter1",$"parameter2")
```

You are passing columns to the function and not primitive datatypes. So, I would suggest you to change your `method1` and `method2` as `udf` functions, if you want to apply *primitive datatype manipulations* inside functions. And `udf` functions would have to return a value for each row of the new column.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def method1 = udf((P1:String, P2:Double)=>{
  print(P1)
  print(P2)
  P1+P2
})

def method2 = udf((P1:String, P2:Double)=>{
  print(P1)
  print(P2)
  P1+P2
})
```

Then your `withColumn` api should work properly

```
df.withColumn("methodCalling", when($"name" === "method1", method1($"parameter1",$"parameter2")).otherwise(when($"name" === "method2", method2($"parameter1",$"parameter2")))).show(false)
```

**Note: udf functions perform data serialization and deserialzation for changing the column dataTypes to be processed row-wise which would increase complexity and a lot of memory usages. [spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) should be used as much as possible**

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to read the JSON and based on that call the methods.

Since you have already created a dataframe, you can do something like :

```
df.map( row => (row.getString(0), row.getString(1) , row.getDouble(2)   ) ).collect
  .foreach { x =>
      x._1.trim.toLowerCase match {
          case "method1" => method1(x._2, x._3) 
        //case "method2" => method2(x._2, x._3)
        //case _ => methodn(x._2, x._3)
      }
   }
// Output : P1name1.0
// Because you used `print` and not `println` ;)
```

Comment: Hi Philantrovert,thanks for reply it is work with above code .but i added some more code in method1 and method2 functions, instead of print statements.But i am getting error like "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable" ...caused by "Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem".please help me on this.thanks in advance .

Comment: please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432964/error-executor-exception-in-task-0-0-in-stage-6-0-spark-scala?noredirect=1#comment81821142_47432964